# kendo grid columns width not adjusting properly If I use column menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo column menu in my grid.If I uncheck item in the columnmenu then the column width are not properly occupying the full width .
can any one help me how to fix this.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data  : createRandomData(100),
        pageSize : 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id       : { type: 'number' },
                    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                    LastName : { type: 'string' },
                    City     : { type: 'string' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    pageable  : true,
    columnMenu: true,
    columns   : [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 100 }
    ],
    dataBound: function () {
        $(".k-header-column-menu").kendoTooltip({
            content: "column menu"
        });
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because the `width` specified for each column. When the grid is initially loaded it ignores the width and just uses it as a proportion of the total. When you use column menu then it forces the width to what you say.

Depending on what you want to achieve simply remove `width` from the column definition or make sure that `Grid` has the desired width.

Example with columns resizing to use full width of the grid here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/2/

If what you want is to resize the table to keep each column width, you should:

1. Define the grid width for example using CSS style
2. Bound a function to columnShow event and add the width of the column to the current width of the Grid.
3. Bound a function to columnHide event and subtract the width of the column to the current width of the Grid.

CSS:

```
#grid {
    width: 300px
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data  : createRandomData(100),
        pageSize : 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id       : { type: 'number' },
                    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                    LastName : { type: 'string' },
                    City     : { type: 'string' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    pageable  : true,
    columnMenu: true,
    columnHide: function (e) {
        this.wrapper.width(grid.wrapper.width() - e.column.width);
    },
    columnShow: function (e) {
        this.wrapper.width(grid.wrapper.width() + e.column.width);
    },
    columns   : [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 100, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 50, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 150 }
    ],
    dataBound: function () {
        $(".k-header-column-menu").kendoTooltip({
            content: "column menu"
        });
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Running example in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/4/

Comment: If I didn't give the width of each column then, In IE all columns are not displaying.

Comment: Which version of IE? Which of the proposed scenarios (JSFiddle links) do you refer to?

Comment: I only have IE 9 available :-( Do you get any error message in IE console?

Comment: One question, when you say that "all columns are not displaying" do you mean column menu or the content of the columns itself?

Comment: content is displaying properly,but first column only displaying,remaining columns are not displaying

Comment: I've found a PC with IE10! Could you try http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/6/ Is the same than before but I've upgraded Kendo UI to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was in same problem, I got solution on [this link](http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2013/04/10/extending-kendo-grid-functionality-with-knockout.aspx)

```
function loadColumnState(columnStateKey: string, realGrid): void
{  
    var colState = JSON.parse($.jStorage.get(columnStateKey));

    if(colState && colState.length > 0) 
    {
        var visibleIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < colState.length; i++) 
        {                
            var column = colState[i];

            // 1. Set correct order first as visibility and width both depend on this.                                     
            var existingIndex = -1;

            if (typeof column.field !== 'undefined')
            {
                existingIndex = findFieldIndex(realGrid, column.field);
            }
            else if (typeof column.commandName !== 'undefined')
            {
                existingIndex = findCommandIndex(realGrid, column.commandName);
            }

            if (existingIndex > -1 && existingIndex != i) // Different index
            {   // Need to reorder
                realGrid.reorderColumn(i, realGrid.columns[existingIndex]);
            }

            // 2. Set visibility state
            var isHidden = (typeof column.hidden === 'undefined') ? false : column.hidden;

            if (isHidden) 
            { 
                realGrid.hideColumn(i); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                realGrid.showColumn(i); 
                ++visibleIndex;
            }

            // 3. Set width
            var width = (typeof column.width === 'undefined') ? null : column.width;

            if(width != null)
            {
                realGrid.columns[i].width = width; // This sets value, whilst rest redraws
                realGrid.thead.prev().find('col:eq(' + visibleIndex + ')').width(width);
                realGrid.table.find('>colgroup col:eq(' + visibleIndex + ')').width(width); 
            }                              
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these way in order to set the columns width with different option (%, px, auto):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TrainingViewModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(t => t.Name).Title("Training Name").Width("%100"); //set width in % 
        columns.Bound(t => t.Date).Title("Date").Width("150px"); //set width in pixel
        columns.Bound(t => t.CityName).Title("City"); //set width auto (no width property)
    })
)
```